# how to insert data in couchdb for cross domain

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

i am using couch db and i want to post data in local host, i want to pass data append to couch db URL without open the couch db my data is save couch db database how can do this process.like i want to save name url=http://127.0.0.1:5984/address/_design/addressbook/index.html?name=lovesrivastava this URL pass through local-host and save data in couch db database. and return true or false

Answer (score 0):

That question is very hard to understand, but I think your question might be this:

You have 2 CouchDB databases, one on the localhost, and another on a "server".  You want to serve a CouchApp from the localhost, but you want saved documents to be saved on the server.  You can't save directly from the browser to the server because that would be "cross domain".

Your idea to "pass through" the local database to the server is not the right approach.  You always need to save your document back to the database where you got it.

What you need is "replication":
You save the document to your local CouchDB, and then "replicate" it up to the server.